# Using prime "'" in Julia variables

Tags: variables, julia

I have many variables and matrices that I would like to call with a prime, like:

`xprime, yprime, rprime` and so on.

I believe that I can't use `x', y', r'` etc. as it is for instance used for matrices transposed.

```
julia> x' = 5
ERROR: syntax: invalid assignment location "x'" around REPL[2]:1
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[2]:1

julia> x = [1,2]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2

julia> x'
1×2 LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Int64,Array{Int64,1}}:
 1  2
```

I am opened to any suggestion of a more convenient way than xprime, yprime etc. which is pretty long and ugly I think.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use prime:

```
julia> x′ = 1
1

julia> x′
1

help?> ′
"′" can be typed by \prime<tab>
```

Notice the difference that I use the `′` (prime), while you tried to use `'` (single quote). Using single quote is not allowed in variable name as it invokes [adjoint](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/#Base.adjoint) operation on a value preceding it (which you can see in your example).

As explained in help for `′` you can type it in in Julia REPL and in most editors configured to support Julia by typing `\prime` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Doing this may meet the original goals, but I would have to say that it is pure evil from the stand-point of readability. The naive reader will likely have no idea that \prime is being used instead of single quote. This is similar to using upper case Alpha as a variable name. See https://gist.github.com/tdunning/219ec70253542253cd66f1021d57e677 for an example.

Comment: Agreed - also I would advise against using any character sequences that would be changed if someone used Unicode normalization on the sequence as it leads to user confusion.

Comment: So at the end, you suggest to use `xprime`, `rprime` like I did first?

Comment: It depends. If you intend your code to be read by other users without any reference then probably yes. However, if your code does not use linear algebra (so there is no risk of confusion with adjoint) and e.g. your code reproduces verbatim the mathematical formulas from some paper (where prime is used) then I think it is OK to use it. In summary I would say: you must be sure that the notation you use does not lead to reader confusion. Another example is that programmers are usually discouraged from making variables with name `l` as under many fonts it looks very similarly to `1`.